# Email App: How to select a subset of IMAP folders to subscribe to?

Tags: email, imap

I would like to set up my email client to subscribe to only a couple of the tens of folders in my work IMAP account. I can't seem to find an option to subscribe/unsubscribe folders in the Android email app on my Samsung Galaxy S2. Am I just not finding it? Or is there another Android email app that provides this (in my opinion rudimentary) functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There are some additional options available in [K-9 Mail](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9), but it offers only the following choices: "All", "Only 1st Class folders", "1st and 2nd Class folders", "All except 2nd Class folders", "None". Not sure if this helps in your case, depends on your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about Gmail app and your work account is also Google account. If its so not only you can chose what IMAP folder to subscribe but also what notification you want on that folder.

- Press Menu -> More -> Settings
- Under Account Settings click your email address
- You'll see a option "Sync inboxes and labels".
- From there you can chose quantity and folders.

Comment: My version of Gmail (2.3.5.2) only allows me to use Google accounts in Gmail. Which version are you talking about?

Comment: My answer assumes that OP's work account is Google Account.